# Unexpected '/'. Escaping special characters with \ may help - Angular 12 build/deploy

Tags: angular, postcss

I've updated my codebase from Angular 11 to 12 recently, and after that, I just can't deploy my code. I can run `ng build` and `ng serve` and it works flawlessly, however, when I run `ng build --prod` I keep getting the following error, probably because of optimizations (minify) made for prod version:

[image]

The file `D:\Code\Airbox\frontend\styles.670357240e7c04682d1d.css:9031:1` does not exist, it's apparently created by the deploy script but I can't see or access it. I've tried to remove comments and imports from my global css file, but the problem keeps happening.

I couldn't find any solution for it across the internet, and I have no clue of what is going on or how I could find a work around.

Comment: there's not even remotely enough info even to try to guess what the problem might be, can you at least post that `deploy` script command?

Comment: npm run deploy is script?

Comment: I have the same issue, on windows everything build fine, but on unix I get the same exception. Error shows up after migration from 11 to 12.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a work around reading [Angular workspace documentaion](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-configuration). Basically, when setting the `--prod`, angular.json, by default, says to optimize all files. Instead of setting `"optimization": false`, not to lose all optimization benefits, I set only my styles optimization to false, so it won't try to minify my CSS files (which was causing the error) and also, `"inlineCritical": false` was also important because if "true", it checks for every single mistake in CSS files and it was telling me I was missing a bracket } somewhere in my code (which is HUGE and there's no easy way I can know where it is but debugging HARD).

PS: Apparently this inlineCritical feature is more accurate on Angular 12, because it had never happened to me until Angular 11, and I also found many other people having the same issue with this guy (inlineCritical). So here are my new optimization configurations in angular.json -> configurations -> production -> optimization:

```json
"optimization": {
   "scripts": true,
   "styles": {
      "minify": false,
      "inlineCritical": false
   },
   "fonts": true
 },
```

I hope it helps someone. If anybody ever finds the `why` answer for this problem, please let us know, I'm really curious about what is going on here.

Comment: how to fix it without  doing it false ?

Answer (score 5):

React/CSS
Issue: static/css/main.css from Css Minimizer plugin
Error: Unexpected '/'. escaping special characters with \ may help.

How to fix it?
1.) Just go to your all css files
2.) next / or * find it in your css files
3.) remove / * already is commended in css file just remove that line entire css files.

example : "/**vijayeswaran**/"  (remove this type cmds)

next you check it **everything is fine**

Answer (score 2):

yeah, I resolved it by commenting out all the css styling and then I was gradually uncommenting it till I found the mistake. I had extra “*/“ in one of the css files. I guess I accidentally left it when commenting/ uncommenting code. So yeah, this is what helped me to resolve the bug.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKlKX.png)

If you are using VS code , install this extension (W3C Web Validator). And go over the CSS files and check whether you CSS is following the W3C standard or not. It will find out the error. I had the same issue.